# How to create a plugin in ES6 (no build system)

Tags: aurelia

I'm trying to move one of my Aurelia custom elements to its own Git repo so that I can `npm install` it and use it in more than one project.

My hope was to simply commit the one JS file the element consists of (it uses an `@inlineView`) (along with a `package.json`) and simply import it into Aurelia, so I did:

1. `$ npm install powerbuoy/my-plugin-name`
2. Added `my-plugin-name` to the list of dependencies in `aurelia.json`
3. Added `use.plugin('my-plugin-name')` to `main.js` (I've also tried with `globalResources()` and `feature()`) (and I've also tried `../node_modules/my-plugin-name/index`).

Nothing seems to work.

Is it correct that my plugin code must *not* be ES6? Does it have to have been transpiled *before* I include it in my project? If that's correct, can someone explain why that's needed and if there's a workaround?

It would be so much easier just to move that one file to its own repo, rather than setting up a whole new skeleton app for one file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plugin can be ES2015, for the most part. The main exception is that you cannot use the `import` module syntax, as that is not supported by any browser yet. This also means that the `export class` syntax that your plugin uses is not supported.

So, at the very least, you'll need to transpile your plugin to CommonJS or AMD module format. If you are using only browsers that support ES2015, and you are using only features that are supported by the browser natively, then you can run the ES2015 code natively, save for the module stuff mentioned above.

Comment: Ok so there's no way to make my Aurelia project that uses the plug-in transpile it before use then? As if it were in the same directory as all my other code. I'm almost tempted to use Git Submodules just to solve this (because then the plug-in would just be part of my normal code and included in its bundle by default)

Comment: Typically, no, you wouldn't have the consuming project handle transpilation of a plugin. That being said, you should be able to get it to be transpiled while inside the `node_modules` or `jspm_packages` folder. It's just not going to be easy, because you're trying to do something the tooling, whether it is Aurelia CLI, Webpack, or JSPM/Gulp, doesn't make easy. 

What is the reasoning for the aversion to distributing the plugin pre-transpiled? You know that you can distribute the plugin pre-transpiled in any number of formats and the consumer can choose which to use, right?

Comment: Yea, the biggest reason is that I don't want to maintain yet _another_ build system. And I don't feel like making my one file, ~50 loc plugin a 20 file 20+ dependency behemoth :P I was hoping it wouldn't require more than just move `elements/my-custom-element.js` to node_modules/. I guess I'll investigate the bare minimum required to transpile the file. The plugin skeleton just includes way too much for my liking.